# Changing default applications doesn't work in system settings or on file types

Tags: default-programs, mime-type

Despite several attempts at a solution, I still can't change the default applications in Ubuntu 11.10. If I change them in system settings they revert back as soon as I close the dialogue. Next time I open the settings, default applications have reverted back to the standards. If I right click a file and try to choose a default application there I get an error message saying "can't create user application configuration folder" etc etc.

I am logged in as the only user created, so I should have rights to change these settings, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

If the fault message went on to say `Not a directory` then simply browse to `~/.local/share` and remove, rename or move the file named *applications* which shouldn't be there and is preventing the creation of an `applications` directory.

Open a terminal to check is there is a `applications` file, type on a terminal

```
nautilus ~/.local/share
```

or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> with nautilus open and navigate to `~/.local/share`.

If there is a file called `applications` there, rename it, or delete it (if find renaming it more secure, just in case).

Comment: Sorry, I picked the wrong answer. @moderation: please ignore the flag.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I've recently found out for this issue: Install Ubuntu-Tweak and there you get an option namely "File Type manager" There you can edit all the default application for all type of files/programs. Give it a try and i'm sure it'll work for you the way it worked for me!

Comment: This is just a workaround the issue. How can we really solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought... have you tried in root? do (in terminal)

```
sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

then type in your password and then edit your values there. Hope this helps!